# Python: reading the same file using multiple workers

Tags: python

I want to have several python processes running (basically 10 uwsgi workers) and they all have to read from the same file at the same time (roughly). The reads involve several `seek()`s follower by one `readline()`.

Am I about to shoot myself in the foot with this?

Comment: With no actual code, the answer is "we have no idea". Probably not as long as no one is writing to the file at the same time though.

Comment: I think concurrent read should be no problem.